# How to collect a string with Stringvar inside Python tkinter?

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I'm trying to get an entered information such as grade and a note. For grade I'm using OptionMenu and it prints perfectly, but my note (biljeska) won't print whatsoever

Code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.today()
class OdabirRazreda():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window2 = tk.Tk()
        g=tk.Button(self.window2,command=self.unos)
        g.pack()

        self.ocjena = tk.StringVar()
        self.razred=tk.StringVar()
        self.biljeska=tk.StringVar()
        self.ucenik=tk.StringVar()
        self.window2.mainloop()

    def unos(self):
        self.window2.withdraw()
        self.window4 = tk.Tk()

        lbl_ocjena = tk.Label(self.window4, text="Ocjena")
        self.lbl_biljeska = tk.Label(self.window4, text="Bilješka:")


        lbl_ocjena.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        self.lbl_biljeska.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)


        ent_ocjena = tk.OptionMenu(self.window4, self.ocjena, "1", "2", "3","4","5")
        ent_ocjena.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, )

        ent_biljeska = tk.Entry(master=self.window4,textvariable=self.biljeska)
        ent_biljeska.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)
        btn_unesi = tk.Button(self.window4, text='Unesi',command=self.ispis)
        btn_unesi.grid(row=3, column=1,pady=2)
        self.window4.mainloop()
    def ispis(self):
        print(dt.day,dt.month,self.ocjena.get(),self.biljeska.get())
OdabirRazreda()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tkinter there is complication with mainloop method, i worked with your code little but outputs are not getting expected but, little convertion to frame methods its working good, if usefull can go throught the code of little modification

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.today()


class OdabirRazreda():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.window2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.window2.pack()

        g = tk.Button(self.window2, command=self.unos,)
        g.pack()

        self.ocjena = tk.StringVar()
        self.razred = tk.StringVar()
        self.biljeska = tk.StringVar()
        self.ucenik = tk.StringVar()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def unos(self):
        self.window2.pack_forget() # 'can call destroy() also if no use in further'
        self.window4 = tk.Frame()
        self.window4.pack()

        lbl_ocjena = tk.Label(self.window4, text="Ocjena")
        self.lbl_biljeska = tk.Label(self.window4, text="Bilješka:")

        lbl_ocjena.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)
        self.lbl_biljeska.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, pady=2)

        ent_ocjena = tk.OptionMenu(self.window4, self.ocjena, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
        ent_ocjena.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, )

        ent_biljeska = tk.Entry(master=self.window4, textvariable=self.biljeska)
        ent_biljeska.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2)

        btn_unesi = tk.Button(self.window4, text='Unesi', command=self.ispis)
        btn_unesi.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2)

    def ispis(self):
        print(dt.day, dt.month, self.ocjena.get(), self.biljeska.get())


OdabirRazreda()
```

just created the frames for both the windows and looping is assigned to main window as root...

Comment: its ok, I too learned a lot from this community